# DateTimePicker сравнение двух дат

Tags: c#, datepicker

Есть два DateTimePicker'a

Как написать условие для проверки, если дата1 раньше дата2, то вывести MessageBox например.

Надо чтобы проверял именно ShortDate(12.12.12)← пример

Дата возбуждения должна быть позже, либо равна дате КУСП.
Но никак не раньше!

HELP GUYS!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят.
Сложность заключалась в не знании того что можно сравнивать именно даты
Value.DATE ← =)

ПРИМЕР↓↓

```
        if(dateTimeDateIntination.Value.Date < dateTimeDateCRB.Value.Date)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Дата возбуждения раньше");
        }
```